# Form submits despite of javascript validation returning false and displaying alert message

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a form to be filled in by the users, and empty fields would prompt JavaScript validation to return a message to fill in that specific field. I'm able to accomplish this all except that in spite of returning an "Alert" message, the form gets submitted. How do I avoid this? Here's my JavaScript:

```
function validateHandAppr(theForm) {

    // Recom or Not Recom  
    if (document.project.rec.selectedIndex == 0) {
        alert("Please Choose the Recommendation Priority .");
        project.rec.focus();
        return false;
    }

    // Recommended priorities 
    if (document.project.rec.selectedIndex == 2 && document.project.recvd_dt.value == "") {

        alert("Fill in the date when culture was received.");
        project.recvd_dt.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (document.project.rec.selectedIndex == 2 && document.project.recvd_by.value == "") {

        alert("Specify who received the culture.");
        project.recvd_by.focus();
        return false;
    }


    if (document.project.rec.selectedIndex == 2 && document.project.recvd_dt.value != "") {
        var validformat = /^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}$/; //.test(project.recvd_dt.value) //Basic check for format validity

        if (!validformat.test(project.recvd_dt.value)) {
            alert("Invalid Date Format. Please enter in the following format: yyyy-mm-dd.")
            return false;
        } else { //Detailed check for valid date ranges
            var yearfield = project.recvd_dt.value.split("-")[0]
            var monthfield = project.recvd_dt.value.split("-")[1]
            var dayfield = project.recvd_dt.value.split("-")[2]
            var dayobj = new Date(yearfield, monthfield - 1, dayfield)
            if ((dayobj.getMonth() + 1 != monthfield) || (dayobj.getDate() != dayfield) || (dayobj.getFullYear() != yearfield)) {
                alert("Invalid Day, Month, or Year range detected. Please correct and submit again.")
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the form where JavaScript is being called:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="project" name="project"
      action="hand_submit_forms.php" method="post"
      onSubmit="return validateHandAppr(this)"
      class="user-info-from-cookie" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Following is the updated code,as per suggested by DaveRandom:

```
      function validateHandAppr(theForm) {

  // Recom or Not Recom  
  //var val=true;
      if ( document.project.rec.selectedIndex == 0 )
       {
          alert ( "Please Choose the Recommendation Priority ." );
      document.project.rec.focus();
          return false;
        }



    // Recommended priorities 
       if ( document.project.rec.selectedIndex ==2 && document.project.recvd_dt.value == "")
       {

            alert("Fill in the date when culture was received.");
         document.project.recvd_dt.focus();
         return false; 
    }

       if ( document.project.rec.selectedIndex ==2 && document.project.recvd_by.value == "")
     {

  alert("Specify who received the culture.");
  document.project.recvd_by.focus();
  return false; 
  }


    if ( document.project.rec.selectedIndex ==2 && document.project.recvd_dt.value != ""){
        var validformat=/^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}$/ ; //.test(project.recvd_dt.value) //Basic check for format validity

        if (!validformat.test(project.recvd_dt.value))
        {
        alert("Invalid Date Format. Please enter in the following format: yyyy-mm-dd.")
        return false;
        }
        else{ //Detailed check for valid date ranges
        var yearfield=project.recvd_dt.value.split("-")[0]
        var monthfield=project.recvd_dt.value.split("-")[1]
        var dayfield=project.recvd_dt.value.split("-")[2]
        var dayobj = new Date(yearfield, monthfield-1, dayfield)
        if ((dayobj.getMonth()+1!=monthfield)||(dayobj.getDate()!=dayfield)||(dayobj.getFullYear()!=yearfield))
        {
        alert("Invalid Day, Month, or Year range detected. Please correct and submit again.")
        return false;}
        else
        {
        return true; }
        }
    }

  //    return val;
      }
```

Comment: Probably one of the `.focus()` calls is causing an error (my guess would be that one of the `project.x` objects doesn't exist for some reason) and `false` is not actually being returned by the function. In the Chrome console (or wherever you are debugging) set the console to preserve log on navigation and you would see an error message logged telling you what the problem is if this is the case.

Comment: In fact that ^^ is the problem. Your validation conditions reference `document.project` but your `.focus()` calls reference simply an unqualified `project` object that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is these lines:

```
project.rec.focus();
// ...
project.recvd_dt.focus();
// ...
project.recvd_by.focus();
```

Your validation conditions reference `document.project` but the above lines represent simply `project` - which does not exist globally because it is a child of `document`, not `window` and you did not declare it locally.

Because these lines are between the `alert()` lines and the `return false;` lines, you will see the alert but the return statement will never be reached - so the function will not return false and the form will be submitted.

If you change the lines to:

```
document.project.rec.focus();
// ...
document.project.recvd_dt.focus();
// ...
document.project.recvd_by.focus();
```

...it should work.

## However

You should assign the functions to the `<form>`s DOM object's `submit` event instead of using inline event handlers.

If you do this, you will be passed an event object to the first argument of the function, and you can use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) instead of returning `false`. This would avoid the problem (if the line was placed before the error occurred), and is generally a better way to handle this, because returning `false` also stops propagation of the event, which may not be desired - actually this makes little difference in this specific case but as a general rule it is true.

If you do this, the handler will be executed in the context of the DOM object - so the `this` variable will be a reference to it, and you won't need to pass it in as an argument.

Comment: Hey I did as suggested by you, and the problem was sorted for project.rec.focus(); but still it exists for the remaining check alerts . Thanks for the explanation but could  you please point out where now am I mistaken?

Comment: Heya Ive pasted the updated code as an edit to the question, since the comment couldnt take more characters. The date type is not being validated , and the form gets submitted after the "Specify who received the culture" error.

Comment: @Snids OK - firstly can you show a little more HTML for the form? I would like to see the form elements that `document.project.*` refer to. Also, do you get any errors logged in the console? If you use Chrome, press F12 and go to the Console tab, then right click on the main body of the console and make sure the "preserve log on navigation" option is checked, then try and repeat the error - you should see an error message logged in the console that will give a clue why the validation code is failing.